# How can an account with a direct ICAP address be created?

Tags: icap

In order for an Ethereum account to be able to have an IBAN-compatible "direct" ICAP address, its raw address must have zeroes in the most-significant 6 bits. In other words it must fit in 154 bits.

The only way I know in which to do that is by brute-force: pick a private key, derive the public key from it, and then the address from that - and repeat until you find one that meets the criterion. There's a 1-in-64 chance each try.

Is that the only way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the only way, iterate until you find a key which fits into 154 bits (address less than `03ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`). That means it has to start with `0x00`, `0x01`, `0x02` or `0x03`.

Some of the libraries support that already, otherwise as mentioned above, using a **vanity address** generator should be able to generate one.

(Vanity addresses are where you define the criteria how the resulting address should look like and usually they do a bruteforce search until such an address is found.)

In Javascript, [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/axic/ethereumjs-wallet) and [ethereumjs-icap](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-icap) can be used to achieve that. Or as a commandline tool, [helpeth](https://github.com/ethereumjs/helpeth):

```
$ helpeth keyGenerate raw true
Address: 0x0008790cf214419f622db6484f07f73c19b4f546
Address (checksum): 0x0008790cf214419F622dB6484f07F73c19b4F546
ICAP: XE52 50DK T7BM 161X 0KHH RZXW FM60 K243 Q
Public key: 0xb146e3092d4177819f52038d26deb203d95c6e18f6c71812b68eafb0db4496366a093607d8e705bd688dedfa68dec9112e0baff256943c90cd221f04565f15eb
Private key: 0x413d8a0009d47eca4522d815b961d255a7aaad775bdefb1de29686a372aaa7c4
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, brute force, or how it is called: *vanity addresses*. You can use Vanityreum and search for raw hex adresses starting with `00`.

```
 $ python2 Vanityreum.py 00
    [...]
Time spent :  6 seconds
Approx global search speed :  42.0  per second
Address :  0065845e01aa87635d2d5a3190fa8eee3e8f1954 
PrivKey :  6135fcd5...3582b873
```

Took me 6 seconds. To convert it into a direct ICAP address, I used `ethkey` to import it into turboethereum:

```
 $ ethkey importbare 6135fcd5...3582b873
Enter a passphrase with which to secure account 0065845e…: 
Please confirm the passphrase by entering it again: 
Successfully imported 6135fcd5...3582b873 as b1aef058-9b81-4933-c4ff-25fba80c7faf0
 $ ethkey inspectbare b1aef058-9b81-4933-c4ff-25fba80c7faf
Enter passphrase for key b1aef058-9b81-4933-c4ff-25fba80c7faf: 
Key b1aef058-9b81-4933-c4ff-25fba80c7faf:
  ICAP: XE431O16GX6C39Q1NMBIZ9V2OYJXQIFVX0
  Raw hex: 0065845e01aa87635d2d5a3190fa8eee3e8f1954
  Secret: 6135fcd51c20ce11...
```

My direct ICAP could be: `XE431O16GX6C39Q1NMBIZ9V2OYJXQIFVX0`, I just dont know how to calculate the checksum correctly, here: assuming it's `43`.

Comment: The hex address can start with `0x00`, `0x01`, `0x02` or `0x03` and fit into the required 154 bits - which would reduce your search by a factor of 4.